# NVP ToDictionary

Tags: c#, linq

Here are 2 records in are sample string, the "|" indicates a new record or row
a "," separates the pairs and a "=" separates the key from the value.  The code below would work if it were a single row or record but not for many rows or in this case 2 rows.
What is needed to have this work so that I get 2 rows with 3 elements each?

```
string s1 = "colorIndex=3,font.family=Helvicta,font.bold=1|colorIndex=7,font.family=Arial,font.bold=0";
string[] t = s1.Split(new[] { '(', ')' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

Dictionary<string, string> dictionary =
                 t.ToDictionary(s => s.Split('=')[0], s => s.Split('=')[1]);
```

Comment: Why are you splitting on ( and )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result = input.Split('|')
                  .Select(r => r.Split(',')
                                .Select(c => c.Split('='))
                                .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]));
```

Comment: Your solution is excellent. Nice, neat and concise. I would suggest that explicitly mentioning that the return type is `IEnumerable<Dictionary<String,String>>` would have been the icing on the cake.

Comment: Thank you so MUCH!  This works perfectly.  I tried about 10 other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to start with

```
class Font {
    public int ColorIndex { get; set; }
    public string FontFamily { get; set; }
    public bool Bold { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
var fonts = s1.Split('|')
  .Select(s => {
      var fields = s.Split(',');
      return new Font {
          ColorIndex = Int32.Parse(fields[0].Split('=')[0]),
          FontFamily = fields[1].Split('=')[1],
          Bold = (bool)Int32.Parse(fields[2].Split('=')[2])
      };
  });
```